# How to create a loop counter while loop is runing?

Tags: php, jquery, foreach

I want to create a counter. I have a foreach loop value. I want show the count while the script is running. How can set a counter while the script is running?

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
    $attrapivalue = $_product->getAttributeText('apivalue');
    $prosku =  $_product->getSku();

    if (!in_array($prosku, $array) && $attrapivalue=="No"){
        echo "<p class='count'>";
        $i++;
        echo "</p>";
    }                   
}

echo "<p class='test'>Total Matched : </p>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Not Found : " .$k;
```

Comment: show some code and tell your problem. thanks.

Comment: and I want a Unicorn

Comment: @annat i have a script using foreach fine . I want to show this each value only count while script is running .

Comment: What is your problem? where is the `jquery` code?

Comment: @ bhavesh i am using ajax for this code...

Answer (score 1):

This question is (or at least should be) entirely unrelated to PHP. Use PHP to output your data, including the total count. Then, use javascript/jQuery to create a visual effect of counting from 0 to the total number, for example on document ready.

```
<p class='test'>Total Matched : <span>888</span></p>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    var item = $('.test > span');
    var total = parseInt(num.text());
    var counter = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
      counter ++;
      item.text(counter);
      if(counter >= total) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 10);
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. The output is only shown after the PHP has finished executing.

PHP stands for: "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor", notice the "Preprocessor" part, it preprocesses the page and creates the HTML, it cannot modify the HTML once it's ran.

Comment: It is possible using `flush()`

Comment: @PHPhil but once it's been output it cannot be modified. You can't keep updating the same piece of HTML.

Comment: @EM-Creations i addded tag there jquery  i want to only way how can i show counter no issue

Comment: @AmanDhiman The only way this will work is if you have a page running JavaScript which then sends off a request to a PHP script and keeps getting back status messages and updating the page, but how you've currently implemented it will not work.

Comment: @PHPhil `flush()` does not always work. It is although not safe to use it. Some browser will still open/close connection regardless usage of `flush()`

Answer (score 0):

You Can't show php's `foreach`'s count while the script is running.

PHP doesn't work that way. PHP is a preprocessor for HTML. It converts the dynamic code into plain html at server side as a whole, and then it sends the whole HTML file to browser.

Thus, you don't have option to show php `loop`'s counter value to the user side.

You Can alternatively use Ajax.  But again, PHP will send whole ajax response at once only after php script finishes execution. You have to implement some javascript loop mechanism at client side to show the counter value one by one as suncat100 suggested.

If you want to show value updating animation to user you can try this,

**PHP**

```
$i=0;
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
    $attrapivalue = $_product->getAttributeText('apivalue');
    $prosku =  $_product->getSku();

    if (!in_array($prosku, $array) && $attrapivalue=="No"){
        echo "<p class='count'>";
        $i++;
        echo "</p>";
    }                   
}
```

**HTML (JS)**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var item = $('.test > span');
    var total = <?php echo $i?>;
    var counter = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
      counter ++;
      item.text(counter);
      if(counter >= total) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 10);
});
</script>
</body>
```

Use the both php and JS code in same page. put the JS code part just before ending `</body>`.